# VB 2008 net keycode

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone help on how to disable the <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd>key in vb.net. I am not using any button to disable. But by default it should start function disable to keys once the application starts.

Comment: What is the `Carl` key?

Comment: Sorry it's alt+ctrl key

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SuppressKeyPress Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress(v=vs.110).aspx). I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but lets say that you dont want a certain key to effect a textbox change. Lets say you don't want the key `G` to be written in the text box. You can write to following code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.G Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
End Sub
```

This code will prevent the key G to be written in the text box. Hoped it helped :)

Comment: I tried mouse enter key too. It is working but what about alt key and ctrl keys pls?